# is my Pronounciation of [ɤ] and french nasal vowels and [ɲ] correct?

Tags: ipa, pronunciation, french

Right now I'm trying to learn how to pronounce different vowel sounds in IPA and i wonder if I'm Pronouncing [ɤ] right.

[ɤ](https://voca.ro/1n0vhRUlhHni)

I've been trying to learning French for a long time and I wonder if my Pronounciations of some of the nasal vowels and [ɲ] are correct.

[/ɲ/](https://voca.ro/1hTinNsTngJa)

[/ɑ̃/](https://voca.ro/1bSjKOXNbh4H)

[/ɛ̃/](https://voca.ro/119nt2GLrfkT)

Comment: Perhaps also supply a short wordlist for more context for our ears. e.g. for /ɛ̃/ you could read 'Invitez vos cousins demain pour boire ce vin'

Comment: [Here,](https://voca.ro/1bR1vYw70Hq2) sorry if I sound bit strange, I'm 16, I actually thought of recording a short wordlist containing the nasal vowels but since my level of French pretty low I wasn't able to think of any examples of the nasal vowels on my own.

Comment: Nice. To my ears, /ɛ̃/ is a bit low, close to /ɑ̃/. There are dialects that pronounce /ɛ̃/ similarly to how you do it, but I think for a learner it's more helpful to distinguish all sounds clearly. If you want some more sentences: /ɲ/ L'agneau ignore vos signes. /ɑ̃/ Donnez-en aux enfants. /ɤ/ is not in French to my knowledge; are you thinking of /ø/ or /œ/?

Comment: Yeah, I know there's /ɤ/ in french, I'm trying to pronounce all the vowel sounds on the IPA vowel chart and I wondered if my attempt at [ɤ] was correct. also is the [ə] sound in French realized as [ ø œ]? it doesn't sound like a true schwa to my ears.

Comment: As already stated, there is **no**  /ɤ/  in French (see [French IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/French)). Your first recording sounds more like a /ɔ/ to my ears.

Comment: People learn languages by pronouning words, not single sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you're still interested, here's what I think.

First, yes, your /ɲ/ is correct.

Second, you're realizing /ɑ̃/ as [õ]. If you do this, you could potentially confuse native speakers, because (as you may have noticed) it's typical to describe [õ] as realizing /ɔ̃/ (which contrasts with /ɑ̃/). For example, FR "penser" is /pɑ̃se/ [pɑ̃se] (EN "to think") whereas FR "poncer" is /pɔ̃se/ [põse] (EN "to sand").

Third, you're realizing /ɛ̃/ as [ã], which is more or less how /ɛ̃/ is realized in standard (Parisian) French. It's typical to describe /ɛ̃/ as being realized by /æ̃/ in standard French, but for me, that's a more Southern realization. Also, it's common in and around Toulouse for /ɛ̃/ to be realized as [ɛ̃].

I hope that the above helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case of /ɤ/, you actually pronounce it like [o̞], with detectable rounding. You need to try more close and less rounded sound.

Comment: what about [this one](https://voca.ro/16Iig8jCWMOe)?

Comment: Can you pronounce it within a syllable? It is too fast to perceive it. But I still hear the slight rounding.

Comment: And this sound still in the open position. You need the closer one.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, [here](https://voca.ro/17FB7Iaqouyo), I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: is [this](https://voca.ro/1cCh6Ms2glAJ) better?

Comment: Yes. In your answer with the 'sorry' beginning, you pronounce it in the more or less right position. But with the diphthongization over its duration: /sɤː/ > /sɤˑɪ̯/. This is usual situation with English speakers especially. They often substitute relative long vovels into diphthongs. NB The length sign /ː/ here denotes relative duration, not absolute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! what about the second recording?

Comment: As in my first anwers: still difficult to perceive it without any one syllable. So my perception is: there are something like /ə̞˗.....ɵ˗/. Your first sound is slightly more open than schwa sound and slightly retracted, and second is more close, more retracted. But it is possible to be just artefacts of the record ending.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I have one more question, can you please tell me what is the phonetic quality of [this vowel](https://voca.ro/1nYdPxF3nN8Y)? is it still [o̞]? to me it seems central/centralized (or advanced) but I'm not sure, here are recordings of me pronouncing this vowel in syllables, [recording](https://voca.ro/16Hn0Yx0AVwu) 1, [recording](https://voca.ro/14gNNsRgEP97) 2, [recording](https://voca.ro/1jGr8kHGZZzz) 3.

Comment: can you please answer my another question? is the final vowel in [this recording](https://voca.ro/1id5tM8TA5WP) realized as a schwa?

Comment: Not very good recording, but for me the final vowel realised something like /ø/.

Comment: can you help me figure the quality of the vowel after /s/ in this [recording](https://vocaroo.com/1lB01SpFsQ2T)? to my ears it sounds like [ɐ] but I'm not sure of its exact quality.

Comment: It is something like /ɐ̝˖/ for me, not so opened as [ɐ] and slightly fronted because of the front consonants' environment.

Comment: and what about the /i/'s after /ʃ/'s? are they centralized/retracted?

Comment: I think it something around the /ɪ/, i.e. /sɐ̝˖ʃɪʃ˖/.

Comment: again thank you very much for helping me figure out the quality of these vowels.

Comment: do you know what kind of an /r/ sound [this](https://voca.ro/1nuIvIEgI1Wf) is? is it tap? or an approximant?

Comment: It's a tap, budd..

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much?